# Piping cut command not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to use piping to achieve some task, and I am facing some issues.

What I am trying is to cut out only the pid of `dockerd` i.e. `696` in my understand `--fields 1` should return the first field  of the text, however it's not happing that way.

```
myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ ps ax | grep dockerd
  696 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
 2777 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dockerd
myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ ps ax | grep docker | cut --delimiter=" " --fields 1


myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ ps ax | grep docker | cut --delimiter=" " --fields 2

2874
myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ ps ax | grep docker | cut --delimiter=" " --fields 3
696
pts/0
myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` is a nice tool if the fields are separated by single fixed characters.  For this case, where a variable number of spaces are used, awk is a better tool:

```
$ ps ax | grep dockerd | awk '{print $1}'
696
2777
```

Or still better:

```
$ ps ax | awk '/dockerd/{print $1}'
696
2777
```

The best solution, however, is:

```
$ pgrep dockerd
696
```

Not only is `pgrep` simpler, it also eliminates the generally unwanted pid of the grep or awk command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below not to match 'grep' itself.

```
$ ps ax | grep '[d]ockerd' | awk '{print $1}'
696
```